# Java printing Class objects in ArrayList

Tags: java

Sailor class

```
public class Sailor {
    private String name;
    private String email;

    public Sailor(String name, String email) {

    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Crew class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Crew {
    private ArrayList<Sailor> sailorList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public Crew() {
        
    }
    
    public void addCrewMember(Sailor sailor) {
        sailorList.add(sailor);
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        String str = ""; 
        for(int i = 0; i < sailorList.size(); i++) {
            str = sailorList.get(i).getName() + sailorList.get(i).getEmail();
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Main program

```
public class ObjectsSailorProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Sailor firstSailor = new Sailor("Frank", "frank@mail.com");
        Sailor secondSailor = new Sailor("Susan", "susan@mail.com");
        Sailor thirdSailor = new Sailor("John", "john@sailors.com");
        Sailor fourthSailor = new Sailor("Ann", "ann@sailors.com");
        
        Crew firstCrew = new Crew();
        Crew secondCrew = new Crew();
                
        firstCrew.addCrewMember(firstSailor);
        firstCrew.addCrewMember(secondSailor);
        firstCrew.addCrewMember(fourthSailor);
        
        secondCrew.addCrewMember(thirdSailor);
        secondCrew.addCrewMember(secondSailor);
        
        System.out.println("=== First crew ===\n" + firstCrew);
        System.out.println("=== Second crew ===\n" + secondCrew);
        
        secondSailor.setEmail("Susan@sailors.com");
        System.out.println("=== Second crew ===\n" + secondCrew);
    }
}
```

I am having trouble printing the crews and I'm not sure if the addCrewMember is correct.
I've tried reading other similar posts but i haven't been able to use the solutions here. So i need help with the addCrewMember and toString methods

Comment: "I am having trouble printing the crews" — What trouble are you having?

Comment: There's an issue in your Sailor constructor. You don't initialise the name and email fields.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't setting the variables neither in constructor nor by calling setters in your `main`.

You can change the constructor as below:

```
public Sailor(String name, String email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
}
```

In your `toString()` method, you're overwriting the `str`. Use `StringBuilder` to append strings into the resulting string. You can modify your `toString()` method as follows:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < sailorList.size(); i++) {
        str.append(i+1)
                .append(". ")
                .append(sailorList.get(i).getName())
                .append(" ")
                .append(sailorList.get(i).getEmail())
                .append("\n");
    }
    return str.toString();
}
```

And your program will give the output:

```
=== First crew ===
1. Frank frank@mail.com
2. Susan susan@mail.com
3. Ann ann@sailors.com

=== Second crew ===
1. John john@sailors.com
2. Susan susan@mail.com

=== Second crew ===
1. John john@sailors.com
2. Susan Susan@sailors.com
```

Answer (score 0):

0> sailor's constructor is wrong-> you're not initializing the data

```
  public Sailor(String name, String email) {
         setEmail(email); //or this.email=email;
         this.name=name; //you may make a setter also for this
        }
```

1> `private ArrayList<Sailor> sailorList = new ArrayList<Sailor>();`
2> the to-string is also wrong: it prints just the last sailor, use `+=` instead of `=`

```
 str +=" "+ sailorList.get(i).getName() + sailorList.get(i).getEmail();
```

This is just personal taste: I prefer "for-each" syntax.

```
for(Sailor s: sailorList){
  out += s.getName()+" "+s.getEmail();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you are not assigning the values in your Sailor constructor so do that.  You should also add any missing get/set methods.

```
public Sailor(String name, String email) {
  this.name = name;
  this.email = email;
}
```

The `addCrewMember(Sailor)` method in `Crew` looks correct but your `toString()` method is flawed.

- You are trying to build a String but you are re-assigning it on each iteration rather then concatenating elements on each iteration.
- Except in very simple cases, you should avoid String concatenation when compose Strings.
- The code is pushing all of the elements together with no separation which means you will have an unreadable blob of characters (e.g. `bobsmithbsmith@boat.comsamsmithssmith@boat.com`)

I would suggest that you write a `toString()` in `Sailor` class.  This example separates the elements of Sailor by commas and wraps the entire entity in curly braces (e.g. "{Sam Smith, ssmith@boat.com}").  Note the use of String.format(..) rather than concatenation.

```
public class Sailor {
  ... stuff ...
  @Override public String toString() {
    return  String.format("{%s, %s}", name, email);
  }
}
```

The `Crew.toString()` method can employ this to compose its String.  The following makes use of the `StringJoiner` class to compose a comma-separated list of elements wrapped in square braces to represent the crew members (e.g. "[{Al Almond, aalmond@boat.com},{Bob Bobson, bbobson@boat.com}]");

```
public class Crew {
  ... stuff ...
  @Override public String toString() {
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",", "[", "]");
    for (Sailor s : sailorList) {
      sj.add(s.toString()); // Sailor.toString() is explicitly invoked here but you could remove that call and it should still be invoked implicitly
    }
    return sj.toString();
  }
}
```